# Scraping tracks' links from YouTube playlist with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all links for tracks from my playlist.

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

playlist = 'minimal_house'

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCt2GxiTBN_RiE-cbP0cmk5Q/playlists'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
tracks = soup.find(title = playlist).get('href')

print(tracks)

url = url + tracks
print(url)

html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer'})

print(links)
```

I couldn't scrape `'a'`; nor by `id`; nor by class name.

[image: example of one track from playlist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's my messy code that works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

playlist = 'minimal_house'

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCt2GxiTBN_RiE-cbP0cmk5Q/playlists'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tracks = soup.find('a', attrs={'title': playlist}).get('href')

print(tracks)

url = 'https://www.youtube.com' + str(tracks)
print(url)

html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a')
links = set([link.get('href') for link in links if link.get('href').count('watch')])

print(links)
```

since class names change base on device request, it's better to get all links in this case.
and you need to use selenium to scroll down to fetch all the list.